# how to perform touch up inside before prepareForSegue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using a Custom `UITableViewCell` and this cell contains round rect.
This round rect is bounded to action touchup inside and same button is used to perform segue to the other View.

prepareForSegue is called first and then it calls the touch up inside method.

Is there any way to make this reversed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call one method on touch up inside
write your code for what you exactly want to do 
and after that you can call your viewcontroller by using following code to perform segue operation
`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"your segue identifier" sender:self];`
Hope that will help.

Answer (score 2):

You've obviously linked your segue from button to the next view controller. Delete it and create a new segue but from view controller to view controller (start at the yellow view controller icon) and give it a name.

Now the segue isn't called automatically. You call it yourself using this code
`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue identifier" sender:self];`

Answer (score 1):

remove segue form StoryBoard.

& write this code in your button action.

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewId"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```