# prepareForSegue is called instead of ib button

Tags: ios, ibaction

I'm new to IOS, so be kind to answer to my question :).
I have a dynamic UITable populated with UIButtons. Two buttons for each row. Buttons are presented as pictures. Before passing to next view I need to keep data of selected button. Buttons have tags (attached when beeing populated in UITableView). 
My problem is that for normal functioning of programm is needed call of 
-(IBAction)firstButtonTag:(id)sender; or -(IBAction)secondButtonTag:(id)sender; (for storage of Tag in singleton class) and than only call of prepareForSegue method, but currently the logic is working only for buttons in first column, for buttons in second is called prepareForSegue (without call of  -(IBAction)secondButtonTag:(id)sender;)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you need, but to me it looks like you just need to do some calls before doing a segue on button press.

Just perform segue programmaticaly in button action handler:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
  ... // do your stuff here
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueId" sender:nil];
}
```

You also need to remove triggered segue from buttons and add manual segue and set its identifier.

Comment: Thank you for your response but the problem is, that I'm using my own UITableViewDetaisCell class, performSegueWithIdentifier couldn't be called as it is method of my UITableViewDetailsController. Please advice something else?

Comment: even so you can bind button touch event to your controller action handler

Comment: If being more detailed, when the button is pressed in first column is called -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender and then only performSegueWithIdentifier, if the button is pressed from second column performSegueWithIdentifier and then only  -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender, may be it is stroryboard issue?

Comment: I think that the order of calls is not determined when there is a triggered segue and touch event handler for a button at the same time. So you need to perform segue inside event handler.

Comment: I have tried methods from post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470641/how-to-perform-touch-up-inside-before-prepareforsegue  but none of them was usefull for my situation, as the calls were implemented from my UITableViewCell class, could you please clarify where should be implemented event handleing in UITableViewController class or in UITableViewCell (where the "-(IBAction)buttonPressed: (id)sender"'s are member methods).

Comment: you should implement event handling in your UITableViewController, in IB you can connect them to your buttons

Comment: I followed your advice and add to                            - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...[cell.firstStickerImageButton addTarget:self selector:@selector(stickerButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];                         ... but I'm reciving error: receiver type 'UIButton' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'addTarget:selector:forControlEvents:

Comment: "addTarget:action:forControlEvents:", not "...selector:..."!

Comment: I have changed to action - [cell.secondStickerImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];, and also added method - (void)ButtonSelected:(id)sender{                       [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"StickerImageSegue" sender: self];} but after the call of -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{} I'm getting error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CatalogCategoriesDetails ButtonSelected]: unrecognized selector sent to instance, so my ButtonSelected method is never called

Comment: My code is working now, Thank you, I've changed logic and button touch up inside is implemented in customed UITableView instead of customed UITableViewCell, but the problem is I don't know how to pass my UIbuttons tag, in order to understand which button was clicked (there are 2 buttons in the row) so indexpath is not option for me.

Comment: you can check you button tag within action handler(ButtonSelected:) via [sender tag] call, this is what you need?

Comment: I've changed -(void)buttonTapped:(id )sender to -(void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)button and getting tag from  int tag = button.tag;, so it works just perfect, thank you again! :)